# how to set hintcolor programmatically

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext

I this specific example I want set hint text color progrommatically but I couldn't change it.

```
public class FloatingHintEditText extends EditText {
    private static enum Animation { NONE, SHRINK, GROW }

    private final Paint mFloatingHintPaint = new Paint();
    private final ColorStateList mHintColors;
    private final float mHintScale;
    private final int mAnimationSteps;

    private boolean mWasEmpty;
    private int mAnimationFrame;
    private Animation mAnimation = Animation.NONE;

    public FloatingHintEditText(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public FloatingHintEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, R.attr.floatingHintEditTextStyle);
    }

    public FloatingHintEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);

        TypedValue typedValue = new TypedValue();
        getResources().getValue(R.dimen.floatinghintedittext_hint_scale, typedValue, true);
        mHintScale = typedValue.getFloat();
        mAnimationSteps = getResources().getInteger(R.dimen.floatinghintedittext_animation_steps);

        mHintColors = getHintTextColors();
        mWasEmpty = TextUtils.isEmpty(getText());
    }

    @Override
    public int getCompoundPaddingTop() {
        final FontMetricsInt metrics = getPaint().getFontMetricsInt();
        final int floatingHintHeight = (int) ((metrics.bottom - metrics.top) * mHintScale);
        return super.getCompoundPaddingTop() + floatingHintHeight;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onTextChanged(CharSequence text, int start, int lengthBefore, int lengthAfter) {
        super.onTextChanged(text, start, lengthBefore, lengthAfter);

        final boolean isEmpty = TextUtils.isEmpty(getText());

        // The empty state hasn't changed, so the hint stays the same.
        if (mWasEmpty == isEmpty) {
            return;
        }

        mWasEmpty = isEmpty;

        // Don't animate if we aren't visible.
        if (!isShown()) {
            return;
        }

        if (isEmpty) {
            mAnimation = Animation.GROW;
            setHintTextColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        } else {
            mAnimation = Animation.SHRINK;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(getHint())) {
            return;
        }

        final boolean isAnimating = mAnimation != Animation.NONE;

        // The large hint is drawn by Android, so do nothing.
        if (!isAnimating && TextUtils.isEmpty(getText())) {
            return;
        }

        mFloatingHintPaint.set(getPaint());
        mFloatingHintPaint.setColor(
                mHintColors.getColorForState(getDrawableState(), mHintColors.getDefaultColor()));

        final float hintPosX = getCompoundPaddingLeft() + getScrollX();
        final float normalHintPosY = getBaseline();
        final float floatingHintPosY = normalHintPosY + getPaint().getFontMetricsInt().top + getScrollY();
        final float normalHintSize = getTextSize();
        final float floatingHintSize = normalHintSize * mHintScale;

        // If we're not animating, we're showing the floating hint, so draw it and bail.
        if (!isAnimating) {
            mFloatingHintPaint.setTextSize(floatingHintSize);
            canvas.drawText(getHint().toString(), hintPosX, floatingHintPosY, mFloatingHintPaint);
            return;
        }

        if (mAnimation == Animation.SHRINK) {
            drawAnimationFrame(canvas, normalHintSize, floatingHintSize,
                    hintPosX, normalHintPosY, floatingHintPosY);
        } else {
            drawAnimationFrame(canvas, floatingHintSize, normalHintSize,
                    hintPosX, floatingHintPosY, normalHintPosY);
        }

        mAnimationFrame++;

        if (mAnimationFrame == mAnimationSteps) {
            if (mAnimation == Animation.GROW) {
                setHintTextColor(mHintColors);
            }
            mAnimation = Animation.NONE;
            mAnimationFrame = 0;
        }

        invalidate();
    }

    private void drawAnimationFrame(Canvas canvas, float fromSize, float toSize,
                                    float hintPosX, float fromY, float toY) {
        final float textSize = lerp(fromSize, toSize);
        final float hintPosY = lerp(fromY, toY);
        mFloatingHintPaint.setTextSize(textSize);
        canvas.drawText(getHint().toString(), hintPosX, hintPosY, mFloatingHintPaint);
    }

    private float lerp(float from, float to) {
        final float alpha = (float) mAnimationFrame / (mAnimationSteps - 1);
        return from * (1 - alpha) + to * alpha;
    }
}
```

So when I call from my activity `mEditText.setHintTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.red))` the color doesn't change
The color changes when I set only from xml.

I tried to do mEditText.invalidate() but it doesn't help too. 
What should I do here to make my hintTextColor red.

Comment: Can you post your activity?

Comment: there is nothing speccial in my activity. I just call mEditText.setHintTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.red))

Answer (score 0):

Make your fields not final and try this:

```
public FloatingHintEditText(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init();
}

public FloatingHintEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init();
}

public FloatingHintEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    init();
}

private void init() {
    TypedValue typedValue = new TypedValue();
    getResources().getValue(R.dimen.floatinghintedittext_hint_scale, typedValue, true);
    mHintScale = typedValue.getFloat();
    mAnimationSteps = getResources().getInteger(R.dimen.floatinghintedittext_animation_steps);

    mHintColors = getHintTextColors();
    mWasEmpty = TextUtils.isEmpty(getText());
}
```

Comment: when I call mEditText.setHintTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.red)) the color doesn't changed, do I missed something?

Comment: @pmb I've tested and the colors are set properly if you change to `setHintTextColor(Color.RED);`. That means there are problems in your logic with your `ColorStateList`.